# Python Socket is leaving grey space at the end of the sent Image

Tags: python, image, sockets

Python Socket Server recieves an image but gets stuck in a loop while saving the image and the image results at the end how do I fix this

I am trying to get a python socket server to recieve an image from a client and then save it. For some reason the server gets stuck on the last 2048 bytes of the image and just stops and it makes the end of the images grey how can i fix this.

```
     # Server side code
    
    if usedata[0] == 'receiveImage':
        file = open(f'ServerSaves/{usedata[1]}','wb')
        print('receiving image...')
        image_chunk = conn.recv(2048)

        while image_chunk:
            file.write(image_chunk)
            image_chunk = conn.recv(2048) # stays on this line of code forever


        file.close()
        print('image received')

     
     # clinet side code does not error

    if dataAlt[0] == 'receiveImage':
        try:

            file = open(f'ClientSaves/{dataAlt[1]}','rb')
            print('sending image...')
            image_data = file.read(2048)

            while image_data:
                s.send(image_data)
                image_data = file.read(2048)

            file.close
            print('image sent')
        except:
            message = f'file {dataAlt[1]} send fail'
            print(message)
```

[image with missing data at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVxNE.jpg)

Comment: You are blindly assuming that `send` will send all data. This assumptions is wrong assuming that you have a TCP socket. Use `sendall` instead.

Comment: Even if `send` isn't dropping any data, if you try to receive more than sent without closing the socket, `recv` will hang waiting for more data with that `while` loop.  Use `sendall` and close or shutdown the sending side of the socket, or send the file size *first* and loop until you receive *exactly* that size.